# Question about definition of rotation on sphere

Tags: rotations

I just started M.A. and I do not have enough knowledge about aforementioned concepts. I truly want to know everything about this mapping in details.
A rotation of the sphere $s^2$ is a map $ r= r_{p,\alpha}$ described by spinning the sphere (actually, spinning the ambient space $R^3$) about the line through the origin and the point $ p\in s^2$, counterclockwise through angle $\alpha $ looking at  $p$  from outside the sphere.
Thus r is the linear map that fixes $p$ and rotates planes orthogonal to $p$ through angle $\alpha$. Let $q$ be a unit vector orthogonal to $p$. then the matrix of r is (viewing p and q as column vectors)
$m_r=
\begin{bmatrix}
p&q&p\times q
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&cos\alpha&-sin\alpha\\
0&sin\alpha&cos\alpha
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p&q&p\times q
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$
please help me to know it.

Comment: Google is your friend

Comment: Please use mathjax formatting.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Coul;d you please format your question using Mathjax? See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation